# Why doesn't React shallow comparisons notice references' changes?

Tags: reactjs

In reactjs.org, at this page https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html, I don’t understand this part:

```
class ListOfWords extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.words.join(',')}</div>;
  }
}

class WordAdder extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      words: ['marklar']
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    // This section is bad style and causes a bug
    const words = this.state.words;
    words.push('marklar');
    this.setState({words: words});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick} />
        <ListOfWords words={this.state.words} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

> The problem is that PureComponent will do a simple comparison between
> the old and new values of this.props.words. Since this code mutates
> the words array in the handleClick method of WordAdder, the old and
> new values of this.props.words will compare as equal, even though the
> actual words in the array have changed. The ListOfWords will thus not
> update even though it has new words that should be rendered.

What I understand from handleClick(), this.state.words physically change (the previous object is replaced by a new one, so new pointer). A shallow comparison should notice it, as it would notice inner changes of any props, isn’t it? Why wouldn’t it be the case here?

Comment: Bonus question : I start all my posts by "Hi everyone!", but Stackoverflow never displays that "hello" message :( Anyone knows why???

Comment: Answer on the bonus question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251077/my-opening-hi-everyone-in-my-question-keeps-disappearing

Comment: Hoooo I see! Legit then, even if I feel it a little pity as, in our world, we are already missing social interactions ^^' But well, that's another story. Thank you for the link @Lazar :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this.state.words physically change (the previous object is replaced by a new one, so new pointer

It doesn't.

The first line just copies the reference. Both `this.state.words` and `words` point to the same array. Do a `words.push('marklar')` and you'll see `this.state.words.length` change as well.

```js
const words = this.state.words;
```

When you do `setState` afterwards, you just "overwrite" `state.words` with `words`, but this doesn't really do anything; you keep the same reference. It's essentially a no-op.

Comment: I see, so JS works with ref in case of assignation operators, I was missing that information. But nevertheless, even is the object reference is the same, so is it with the "correct way of doing things" that React recommends, isn't it: "words: state.words.concat(['marklar'])" ? It concatenate "in place", or am I again missing something? Furthermore, even in we keep the same object reference, in the “incorrect code”, we push a word, so the length changes anyway. Why a PureComponent wouldn’t notice that change?

Comment: "concat" returns a new array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: THank you, I was indeed missing something :( And never mind for the for the second sub-question ^^ "shallow comparison" does not check the contents inside the array"

Comment: The length changes, but the length is just a property on an array. The array reference itself doesn't change, ie. `old == new`, even though `old.length != new.length`.

Answer (score 2):

> handleClick(), this.state.words physically change (the previous object is replaced by a new one, so new pointer)

This is not true. Let's take a look at what this method does:

```
handleClick() {
  // This section is bad style and causes a bug
  const words = this.state.words; // words is now a reference to the array
  words.push('marklar'); // we add an item to the array. reference doesn't change
  setState({words: words}); // we update state setting words to the same array reference
}
```

Now, in the next re-render when react compares previous `words` array and new `words` array, it finds that the array reference is the same.

"shallow comparison" does not check the contents inside the array. It checks the reference to see whether it is new or not

Comment: Thank you so much! That "shallow comparison does not check the contents inside the array" is what I was missing. Furthermore, I was not aware that JS concat creates a new instance of the object it concatenate. It's so... counter intuitive for a C++ developer like myself :( So the time we earn but using a PureComponent, we lose it by creating a whole new object ^^'